# Is accessing global data faster than accessing local data?

Tags: performance, memory, ram

The question is more about how DRAM works.

(speaking in C terms) If I have a local(located on stack) variable and a global(static or dynamically allocated) variable, which one would be accessed faster?
Considering that neither one is cached or placed in a register!

So the actual question is whether it is faster to retrieve data that is close to previously touched area than to retrieve data that is in completely different place, say, row address and column address are different from previous.

If there's indeed a difference in access times, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the question was

> whether it is faster to retrieve data that is close to previously touched
>   area than to retrieve data that is in completely different place

The answer is yes, it is faster.

TL;DR: DRAM has a buffer(a cache, if you please, though it's not really a cache)

And the reason to that is DRAM workings.

- A [SIMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMM) is 1 or 2 ranks that consist of multiple DRAM chips([ICs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit)).
  [image: SIMM scheme]
- Each IC consists of multiple banks(rows of bytes + row/column decoder + row buffer)
  [image: banks scheme]
- If ICs are numbered 0 through *K*, banks 0 through *M*, and rows 0 through *N*;
  then rows (*0*, *m*, *n*), (*1*, *m*, *n*) ... (*K*, *m*, *n*) constitute a memory page(data of successive addresses).
- (a common case) If a given SIMM has 8 ICs per rank and a bank has 1024 columns(each is a byte), a memory page(or the overall buffered memory) is 8KB in size.

With that said, if you access an address that is on the same memory page as the last address that was requested for this same bank, only the column decoder would be engaged, which is ~2 times faster then when the address is on a different page. Note: the 2 times difference is only relative to DRAM and is not relative to the overall time to get to the CPU, which still would be >100ms.

There's a lot of details to be added, but I'm not proficient at all to do that.

P.S. this topic is not widely discussed and all of the above is just a very short overview of what made sense to me from examining not very well written information.

Answer (score 3):

There’s no difference in general.  DRAM works the same whether a given address is on the stack or the heap.  In practice, there are several cases where a local variable is often faster:

- The first few bytes of the stack are practically always in the cache, and the first time you access a static variable, it probably will not be.
- Compilers can often statically analyze the lifetime of a local variable and optimize it into a register, eliminating the memory access entirely, whereas a global variable usually must be loaded and stored, because another part of the program might have changed it before and could refer to it later.
- On many architectures, the machine instruction to access a memory location  relative to the stack pointer is more efficient than the machine instructions to access an arbitrary static address.

Complicating things is that “local/global” is probably not the the distinction you really mean.  For example, many languages have “static local” variables that are implemented like globals, but lexically local, and “thread-local” variables that are lexically non-local but stored on the stack.  And if you pass a locally-allocated variable by reference far down the call chain, it will eventually fall out of the cache and behave exactly like a global.